# Filter nested relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a nested relationships that goes likes this:

> template has many groups, groups has many estructures

using Laravel relationships I can easily get the data I need from templates.

But I also have another model called elements, elements belongs to a template, also an element has many data, that is a instanciated "estructures" that belongs to a especific element.

If I try to use Laravel relationships to get an element like this:

```
{
  element: {
    ...,
    groups: [
      {
        ...,
        estructure: []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the estructure is filled with all the estructure that belongs to the template, but I need to filter it so it only shows the estructure that belongs to the element.

I can achieve it by passing the id of the element, it works when I try to search for an especific element.

```php
  $element = \App\Element::where('id', $elementID)->with(['template.groups.estructure' => function ($query) use ($elementID) {

    $query->where('element_id', $elementID)

  }])->get();
```

The problem comes when I try to get multiple elements.

```php
  $elements = \App\Element::with('template.groups.estructure')->get();
```

Comment: Does the `estructures` table have an `element_id` on it?

Comment: @RossWilson Element has estructure_id as its a one to many relationship

Comment: So an `Element` hasMany `Group`, `Group` hasMany `Estructure` and then `Estructure` hasMany `Element`??